# Add Header and Footer for PDF using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

How can I add header and footer for each page in the pdf.

Headed will contain just a text
Footer will contain a text and pagination for pdf (Page : 1 of 4)

How is this possible ? I tried to add the below line, but header does not show up in pdf.

```
document.AddHeader("Header", "Header Text");
```

This the code I am using for generation PDF :

```
   protected void GeneratePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = getData(); 

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Locations.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            Document document = new Document();

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);

            document.Open();

            iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER , 8);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
            PdfPRow row = null;
            float[] widths = new float[] { 6f, 6f, 2f, 4f, 2f };

            table.SetWidths(widths);

            table.WidthPercentage = 100;
            int iCol = 0;
            string colname = "";
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Locations"));

            cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {

                table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
            }

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font5));
                }
            }
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();

            Response.Write(document);
            Response.End();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: May be this help full to you. http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx

Comment: Coming to the same question for both the old and the new ITextSharp version, nice!

Answer (score 49):

As already answered by @Bruno you need to use pageEvents.

Please check out the sample code below:

```
private void CreatePDF()
{
    string fileName = string.Empty;    
    DateTime fileCreationDatetime = DateTime.Now;    
    fileName = string.Format("{0}.pdf", fileCreationDatetime.ToString(@"yyyyMMdd") + "_" + fileCreationDatetime.ToString(@"HHmmss"));    
    string pdfPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\PDFs\") +   fileName;

    using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        //step 1
        using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 140f, 10f))
        {
            try
            {
                // step 2
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
                pdfWriter.PageEvent = new Common.ITextEvents();

                //open the stream 
                pdfDoc.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello world. Checking Header Footer", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 22));    
                    para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;    
                    pdfDoc.Add(para);    
                    pdfDoc.NewPage();
                }

                pdfDoc.Close();    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }    
            finally
            { 
            }    
        }    
    }
}
```

And create one class file named ITextEvents.cs and add following code:

```
public class ITextEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
{    
    // This is the contentbyte object of the writer
    PdfContentByte cb;

    // we will put the final number of pages in a template
    PdfTemplate headerTemplate, footerTemplate;

    // this is the BaseFont we are going to use for the header / footer
    BaseFont bf = null;

    // This keeps track of the creation time
    DateTime PrintTime = DateTime.Now;    

    #region Fields
    private string _header;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set { _header = value; }
    }
    #endregion    

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintTime = DateTime.Now;
            bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb = writer.DirectContent;
            headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(100, 100);
            footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {    
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
        {    
        }
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);    
        iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);    
        iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontBig = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);    
        Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Sample Header Here", baseFontNormal);

        //Create PdfTable object
        PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(3);

        //We will have to create separate cells to include image logo and 2 separate strings
        //Row 1
        PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell pdfCell2 = new PdfPCell(p1Header);
        PdfPCell pdfCell3 = new PdfPCell();
        String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";    

        //Add paging to header
        {
            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(200), document.PageSize.GetTop(45));
            cb.ShowText(text);
            cb.EndText();
            float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 12);
            //Adds "12" in Page 1 of 12
            cb.AddTemplate(headerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(200) + len, document.PageSize.GetTop(45));
        }
        //Add paging to footer
        {
            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(180), document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
            cb.ShowText(text);
            cb.EndText();
            float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 12);
            cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(180) + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
        }

        //Row 2
        PdfPCell pdfCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sub Header Description", baseFontNormal));

        //Row 3 
        PdfPCell pdfCell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date:" + PrintTime.ToShortDateString(), baseFontBig));
        PdfPCell pdfCell6 = new PdfPCell();
        PdfPCell pdfCell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("TIME:" + string.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now), baseFontBig));    

        //set the alignment of all three cells and set border to 0
        pdfCell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfCell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfCell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfCell4.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfCell5.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfCell6.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfCell7.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;    

        pdfCell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        pdfCell3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        pdfCell4.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
        pdfCell5.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        pdfCell6.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        pdfCell7.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;    

        pdfCell4.Colspan = 3;  

        pdfCell1.Border = 0;
        pdfCell2.Border = 0;
        pdfCell3.Border = 0;
        pdfCell4.Border = 0;
        pdfCell5.Border = 0;
        pdfCell6.Border = 0;
        pdfCell7.Border = 0;    

        //add all three cells into PdfTable
        pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell1);
        pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell2);
        pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell3);
        pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell4);
        pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell5);
        pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell6);
        pdfTab.AddCell(pdfCell7);

        pdfTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80f;
        pdfTab.WidthPercentage = 70;
        //pdfTab.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;    

        //call WriteSelectedRows of PdfTable. This writes rows from PdfWriter in PdfTable
        //first param is start row. -1 indicates there is no end row and all the rows to be included to write
        //Third and fourth param is x and y position to start writing
        pdfTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, document.PageSize.Height - 30, writer.DirectContent);
        //set pdfContent value

        //Move the pointer and draw line to separate header section from rest of page
        cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
        cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.Height - 100);
        cb.Stroke();

        //Move the pointer and draw line to separate footer section from rest of page
        cb.MoveTo(40, document.PageSize.GetBottom(50) );
        cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.GetBottom(50));
        cb.Stroke();
    }

    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

        headerTemplate.BeginText();
        headerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
        headerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        headerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
        headerTemplate.EndText();

        footerTemplate.BeginText();
        footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
        footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        footerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
        footerTemplate.EndText();  
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I like this example, but I have one question: If I use your PdfPageEventHelper class as a common class for all my PDF documents and I want to display different text in the header of each document (such as document title ...etc) how do I set that? Thanks.

Comment: You can create property for each item that needs to be set dynamically by user. For example "Sample Header Here", could be replaced with property and it's value could be set at run time. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Working perfectlly!! Need help to remove the appending TotalCount to page footer text as I am placing different text in the footer. The page count will be appening to any string I am placing

Comment: Great approach!!! I just updated one line in the `OnCloseDocument()` method, I removed the `-1` to the `writer.PageNumber-1`  string, because as you shared it I always got `Page: pageNumber/pageNumber-1`.

Comment: I'm not able to find a PageEvent object in the PdfWriter.  I verified on iText's API website... doesn't seem to exist.  Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 10):

For iTextSharp 4.1.6, the last version of iTextSharp that was licensed as [LGPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License), the solution provided by [Alvaro Patiño](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4876015/alvaro-pati%c3%b1o) is both simple and effective.

Because documentation is somewhat scarse I'd like to extend his answer with this code snippet that can be used to change the appearance of the header and footer. By default they have a rather large font-size and a thick border, which many people will want to change.

```
// Parameters passed on to the function that creates the PDF 
String headerText = "Your header text";
String footerText = "Page";

// Define a font and font-size in points (plus f for float) and pick a color
// This one is for both header and footer but you can also create seperate ones
Font fontHeaderFooter = FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8f);
fontHeaderFooter.Color = Color.GRAY;

// Apply the font to the headerText and create a Phrase with the result
Chunk chkHeader = new Chunk(headerText, fontHeaderFooter);
Phrase p1 = new Phrase(chkHeader);

// create a HeaderFooter element for the header using the Phrase
// The boolean turns numbering on or off
HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(p1, false);

// Remove the border that is set by default
header.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
// Align the text: 0 is left, 1 center and 2 right.
header.Alignment = 1;

// add the header to the document
document.Header = header;

// The footer is created in an similar way

// If you want to use numbering like in this example, add a whitespace to the
// text because by default there's no space in between them
if (footerText.Substring(footerText.Length - 1) != " ") footerText += " ";

Chunk chkFooter = new Chunk(footerText, fontHeaderFooter);
Phrase p2 = new Phrase(chkFooter);

// Turn on numbering by setting the boolean to true
HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(p2, true);
footer.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
footer.Alignment = 1;

document.Footer = footer;

// Open the Document for writing and continue creating its content
document.Open();
```

For more info check [Creating PDFs with iTextSharp](http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext.aspx) and [iTextSharp - Adding Text with Chunks, Phrases and Paragraphs](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/82/itextsharp-adding-text-with-chunks-phrases-and-paragraphs). The source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6/tree/master/iTextSharp/text) may also be useful.

Answer (score 9):

We don't talk about iTextSharp anymore. You are using iText 5 for .NET. The current version is iText 7 for .NET.

**Obsolete answer:**

The `AddHeader` has been deprecated a long time ago and has been removed from iTextSharp. Adding headers and footers is now done using [page events](https://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/page-events-itext-5). The examples are in Java, but you can find the C# port of the examples [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5) and [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6) (scroll to the bottom of the page for links to the `.cs` files).

Make sure you read the documentation. A common mistake by many developers have made before you, is adding content in the `OnStartPage`. You should only add content in the `OnEndPage`. It's also obvious that you need to add the content at absolute coordinates (for instance using `ColumnText`) and that you need to reserve sufficient space for the header and footer by defining the margins of your document correctly.

**Updated answer:**

If you are new to iText, you should use iText 7 and use event handlers to add headers and footers. See [chapter 3](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers) of the iText 7 Jump-Start Tutorial for .NET.

When you have a `PdfDocument` in iText 7, you can add an event handler:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new MyEventHandler());
```

This is an example of *the hard way* to add text at an absolute position (using `PdfCanvas`):

```
protected internal class MyEventHandler : IEventHandler {
    public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        int pageNumber = pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
        
        //Add header
        pdfCanvas.BeginText()
            .SetFontAndSize(C03E03_UFO.helvetica, 9)
            .MoveText(pageSize.GetWidth() / 2 - 60, pageSize.GetTop() - 20)
            .ShowText("THE TRUTH IS OUT THERE")
            .MoveText(60, -pageSize.GetTop() + 30)
            .ShowText(pageNumber.ToString())
            .EndText();
        pdfCanvas.Release();
    }
}
```

This is a slightly higher-level way, using `Canvas`:

```
protected internal class MyEventHandler : IEventHandler {
    public virtual void HandleEvent(Event @event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        int pageNumber = pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
        
        //Add watermark
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, page.getPageSize());
        canvas.setFontColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, 60);
        canvas.setProperty(Property.FONT, helveticaBold);
        canvas.showTextAligned(new Paragraph("CONFIDENTIAL"),
            298, 421, pdfDoc.getPageNumber(page),
            TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 45);
        pdfCanvas.Release();
    }
}
```

There are other ways to add content at absolute positions. They are described in the different [iText books](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books).

Comment: Not entirely true. Using page events is one way to add headers/footers, but you can add them by using `Document.Header` or `Document.Footer`.

Comment: Dear Dom, if you can add headers and footers with `Document.Header` or `Document.Footer`, you're using a version of iText that is no longer supported: http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Both C# links provided are no longer there. Pls provide anyother source

Comment: @Syed The links no longer make sense. iTextSharp 5 has been replaced with iText 7 for .NET. I've updated the obsolete answer (it dates from **more than 4 years ago!**) and I've added the code that should be used with the most recent version of iText for .NET.

Answer (score 5):

The answers to this question, while they are correct, are very unnecessarily complicated. It doesn't take that much code for text to show up in the header/footer. Here is a simple example of adding text to the header/footer.

The current version of iTextSharp works by implementing a callback class which is defined by the `IPdfPageEvent` interface. From what I understand, it's not a good idea to add things during the `OnStartPage` method, so instead I will be using the `OnEndPage` page method. The events are triggered depending on what is happening to the `PdfWriter`

First, create a class which implements `IPdfPageEvent`. In the:

```
public void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
```

function, obtain the `PdfContentByte` object by calling

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
```

Now you can add text very easily:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

cb.BeginText();
cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 12.0f);
//Note, (0,0) in this case is at the bottom of the document
cb.SetTextMatrix(document.LeftMargin, document.BottomMargin); 
cb.ShowText(String.Format("{0} {1}", "Testing Text", "Like this"));
cb.EndText();
```

So the full for the `OnEndPage` function will be:

```
public void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

    cb.BeginText();
    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 12.0f);
    cb.SetTextMatrix(document.LeftMargin, document.BottomMargin);
    cb.ShowText(String.Format("{0} {1}", "Testing Text", "Like this"));
    cb.EndText();

}
```

This will show up at the bottom of your document. One last thing. Don't forget to assign the `IPdfPageEvent` like this:

```
writter.PageEvent = new PDFEvents();
```

To the `PdfWriter` writter object

For the **header** it is very similar. Just flip the `SetTextMatrix` y coordinate:

```
cb.SetTextMatrix(document.LeftMargin, document.PageSize.Height - document.TopMargin);
```

Comment: The solution without tables, is easier than the others. Lol is crazy what we have to do to add a simple foot and header.

Answer (score 4):

Just add this line before opening the document (must be before):

```
        document.Header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Header Text"), false);
        document.Open();
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain *why* you need to do this, or *how* it works?

Comment: Hi, it has to be before opening the document if you want the header to be shown on the first page, if you don't need that, you can put it after. I know the new way to do it is through the PdfPageEvent, but this is an easy way if you dont need that much control over the header or footer. How it works... there is not much documentation about it.

Comment: Aha. Many thanks for explaining that - I'm hopeful that the extra information will aid others.

Comment: Thank you! Very simple and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

**For those just needing headers!!!**

All of these answers are way too complicated if you are designing your page via `PdfPTables` (which is the easiest way IMO)! If you are working with `PdfPTables` you can literally just define your first `x` number of table rows as header rows. They will then repeat on every page.

No need to invoke bulky page events.

1 line of code:

`myPdfPTable.HeaderRows = myHeaderRowsAmount`

Answer (score 0):

Easy codes that work successfully:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 .
 .       
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
  .
  .
  iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 54, 54);
  iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
  writer.PageEvent = new HeaderFooter();
  doc.Open();
  .
  .
  // make your document content..
  .
  .                   
  doc.Close();
  writer.Close();

  // output
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf;";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=clientfilename.pdf");
  byte[] pdf = ms.ToArray();
  Response.OutputStream.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
 }
 .
 .
 .
}
class HeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
{
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{

    // Make your table header using PdfPTable and name that tblHeader
    .
    . 
    tblHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, page.Left + document.LeftMargin, page.Top, writer.DirectContent);
    .
    .
    // Make your table footer using PdfPTable and name that tblFooter
    .
    . 
    tblFooter.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, page.Left + document.LeftMargin, writer.PageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin), writer.DirectContent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using DataLayer;

namespace DataMngt.MyCode
{
    public class HeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        #region Startup_Stuff

        private string[] _headerLines;
        private string _footerLine;

        private DefineFont _boldFont;
        private DefineFont _normalFont;

        private iTextSharp.text.Font fontTxtBold;
        private iTextSharp.text.Font fontTxtRegular;

        private int _fontPointSize = 0;

        private bool hasFooter = false;
        private bool hasHeader = false;

        private int _headerWidth = 0;
        private int _headerHeight = 0;

        private int _footerWidth = 0;
        private int _footerHeight = 0;

        private int _leftMargin = 0;
        private int _rightMargin = 0;
        private int _topMargin = 0;
        private int _bottomMargin = 0;

        private PageNumbers NumberSettings;

        private DateTime runTime = DateTime.Now;             

        public enum PageNumbers
        {
            None,
            HeaderPlacement,
            FooterPlacement
        }

        // This is the contentbyte object of the writer
        PdfContentByte cb;

        PdfTemplate headerTemplate;
        PdfTemplate footerTemplate;

        public string[] headerLines
        {
            get
            {
                return _headerLines;
            }
            set
            {
                _headerLines = value;
                hasHeader = true;
            }
        }

        public string footerLine
        {
            get
            {
                return _footerLine;
            }
            set
            {
                _footerLine = value;
                hasFooter = true;
            }
        }

        public DefineFont boldFont
        {
            get
            {
                return _boldFont;
            }
            set
            {
                _boldFont = value;
            }
        }

        public DefineFont normalFont
        {
            get
            {
                return _normalFont;
            }
            set
            {
                _normalFont = value;
            }
        }

        public int fontPointSize
        {
            get
            {
                return _fontPointSize;
            }
            set
            {
                _fontPointSize = value;
            }
        }

        public int leftMargin
        {
            get
            {
                return _leftMargin;
            }
            set
            {
                _leftMargin = value;
            }
        }

        public int rightMargin
        {
            get
            {
                return _rightMargin;
            }
            set
            {
                _rightMargin = value;
            }
        }

        public int topMargin
        {
            get
            {
                return _topMargin;
            }
            set
            {
                _topMargin = value;
            }
        }

        public int bottomMargin
        {
            get
            {
                return _bottomMargin;
            }
            set
            {
                _bottomMargin = value;
            }
        }

        public int headerheight
        {
            get
            {
                return _headerHeight;
            }
        }

        public int footerHeight
        {
            get
            {
                return _footerHeight;
            }
        }

        public PageNumbers PageNumberSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return NumberSettings;
            }

            set
            {
                NumberSettings = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Write_Headers_Footers

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            if (hasHeader)
            {
                // left side is the string array passed in
                // right side is a built in string array (0 = date, 1 = time, 2(optional) = page)
                float[] widths = new float[2] { 90f, 10f };

                PdfPTable hdrTable = new PdfPTable(2);
                hdrTable.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - (_leftMargin + _rightMargin);
                hdrTable.WidthPercentage = 95;
                hdrTable.SetWidths(widths);
                hdrTable.LockedWidth = true;

                for (int hdrIdx = 0; hdrIdx < (_headerLines.Length < 2 ? 2 : _headerLines.Length); hdrIdx ++)
                {
                    string leftLine = (hdrIdx < _headerLines.Length ? _headerLines[hdrIdx] : string.Empty);

                    Paragraph leftPara = new Paragraph(5, leftLine, (hdrIdx == 0 ? fontTxtBold : fontTxtRegular));

                    switch (hdrIdx)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            {
                                leftPara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                                PdfPCell leftCell = new PdfPCell(leftPara);
                                leftCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                leftCell.Border = 0;

                                string rightLine = string.Format(SalesPlanResources.datePara, runTime.ToString(SalesPlanResources.datePrintMask));
                                Paragraph rightPara = new Paragraph(5, rightLine, (hdrIdx == 0 ? fontTxtBold : fontTxtRegular));
                                rightPara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                                PdfPCell rightCell = new PdfPCell(rightPara);
                                rightCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                rightCell.Border = 0;

                                hdrTable.AddCell(leftCell);
                                hdrTable.AddCell(rightCell);

                                break;
                            }

                        case 1:
                            {
                                leftPara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                                PdfPCell leftCell = new PdfPCell(leftPara);
                                leftCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                leftCell.Border = 0;

                                string rightLine = string.Format(SalesPlanResources.timePara, runTime.ToString(SalesPlanResources.timePrintMask));
                                Paragraph rightPara = new Paragraph(5, rightLine, (hdrIdx == 0 ? fontTxtBold : fontTxtRegular));
                                rightPara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                                PdfPCell rightCell = new PdfPCell(rightPara);
                                rightCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                rightCell.Border = 0;

                                hdrTable.AddCell(leftCell);
                                hdrTable.AddCell(rightCell);

                                break;
                            }

                        case 2:
                            {
                                leftPara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                                PdfPCell leftCell = new PdfPCell(leftPara);
                                leftCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                leftCell.Border = 0;

                                string rightLine;
                                if (NumberSettings == PageNumbers.HeaderPlacement)
                                {
                                    rightLine = string.Concat(SalesPlanResources.pagePara, writer.PageNumber.ToString());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    rightLine = string.Empty; 
                                }
                                Paragraph rightPara = new Paragraph(5, rightLine, fontTxtRegular);
                                rightPara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                                PdfPCell rightCell = new PdfPCell(rightPara);
                                rightCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                rightCell.Border = 0;

                                hdrTable.AddCell(leftCell);
                                hdrTable.AddCell(rightCell);

                                break;
                            }

                        default:
                            {
                                leftPara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                                PdfPCell leftCell = new PdfPCell(leftPara);
                                leftCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                                leftCell.Border = 0;
                                leftCell.Colspan = 2;                               

                                hdrTable.AddCell(leftCell);

                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }

                hdrTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, _leftMargin, document.PageSize.Height - _topMargin, writer.DirectContent);

                //Move the pointer and draw line to separate header section from rest of page
                cb.MoveTo(_leftMargin, document.Top + 10);
                cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - _leftMargin, document.Top + 10);
                cb.Stroke();
            }

            if (hasFooter)
            {
                // footer line is the width of the page so it is centered horizontally 
                PdfPTable ftrTable = new PdfPTable(1);
                float[] widths = new float[1] {100 };

                ftrTable.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 10;
                ftrTable.WidthPercentage = 95;
                ftrTable.SetWidths(widths);

                string OneLine;

                if (NumberSettings == PageNumbers.FooterPlacement)
                {
                    OneLine = string.Concat(_footerLine, writer.PageNumber.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    OneLine = _footerLine;
                }

                Paragraph onePara = new Paragraph(0, OneLine, fontTxtRegular);
                onePara.Font.Size = _fontPointSize;

                PdfPCell oneCell = new PdfPCell(onePara);
                oneCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER; 
                oneCell.Border = 0;
                ftrTable.AddCell(oneCell);

                ftrTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, _leftMargin, (_footerHeight), writer.DirectContent);

                //Move the pointer and draw line to separate footer section from rest of page
                cb.MoveTo(_leftMargin, document.PageSize.GetBottom(_footerHeight + 2));
                cb.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - _leftMargin, document.PageSize.GetBottom(_footerHeight + 2));
                cb.Stroke();
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region Setup_Headers_Footers_Happens_here

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            // create the fonts that are to be used
            // first the hightlight or Bold font
            fontTxtBold = FontFactory.GetFont(_boldFont.fontFamily, _boldFont.fontSize, _boldFont.foreColor);
            if (_boldFont.isBold)
            {
                fontTxtBold.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
            }
            if (_boldFont.isItalic)
            {
                fontTxtBold.SetStyle(Font.ITALIC);
            }
            if (_boldFont.isUnderlined)
            {
                fontTxtBold.SetStyle(Font.UNDERLINE);
            }

            // next the normal font
            fontTxtRegular = FontFactory.GetFont(_normalFont.fontFamily, _normalFont.fontSize, _normalFont.foreColor);
            if (_normalFont.isBold)
            {
                fontTxtRegular.SetStyle(Font.BOLD);
            }
            if (_normalFont.isItalic)
            {
                fontTxtRegular.SetStyle(Font.ITALIC);
            }
            if (_normalFont.isUnderlined)
            {
                fontTxtRegular.SetStyle(Font.UNDERLINE);
            }

            // now build the header and footer templates
            try
            {
                float pageHeight = document.PageSize.Height;
                float pageWidth = document.PageSize.Width;

                _headerWidth = (int)pageWidth - ((int)_rightMargin + (int)_leftMargin);
                _footerWidth = _headerWidth;

                if (hasHeader)
                {
                    // i basically dummy build the headers so i can trial fit them and see how much space they take.
                    float[] widths = new float[1] { 90f };

                    PdfPTable hdrTable = new PdfPTable(1);
                    hdrTable.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - (_leftMargin + _rightMargin);
                    hdrTable.WidthPercentage = 95;
                    hdrTable.SetWidths(widths);
                    hdrTable.LockedWidth = true;

                    _headerHeight = 0;

                    for (int hdrIdx = 0; hdrIdx < (_headerLines.Length < 2 ? 2 : _headerLines.Length); hdrIdx++)
                    {
                        Paragraph hdrPara = new Paragraph(5, hdrIdx > _headerLines.Length - 1 ? string.Empty : _headerLines[hdrIdx], (hdrIdx > 0 ? fontTxtRegular : fontTxtBold));
                        PdfPCell hdrCell = new PdfPCell(hdrPara);
                        hdrCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                        hdrCell.Border = 0;
                        hdrTable.AddCell(hdrCell);
                        _headerHeight = _headerHeight + (int)hdrTable.GetRowHeight(hdrIdx);
                    }

                    // iTextSharp underestimates the size of each line so fudge it a little 
                    // this gives me 3 extra lines to play with on the spacing
                    _headerHeight = _headerHeight + (_fontPointSize * 3);

                }

                if (hasFooter)
                {
                    _footerHeight = (_fontPointSize * 2);
                }

                document.SetMargins(_leftMargin, _rightMargin, (_topMargin + _headerHeight), _footerHeight);

                cb = writer.DirectContent;

                if (hasHeader)
                {
                    headerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(_headerWidth, _headerHeight);
                }

                if (hasFooter)
                {
                    footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(_footerWidth, _footerHeight);
                }
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {

            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {

            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Cleanup_Doc_Processing

        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            if (hasHeader)
            {
                headerTemplate.BeginText();
                headerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);

                if (NumberSettings == PageNumbers.HeaderPlacement)
                {
                }

                headerTemplate.EndText();
            }

            if (hasFooter)
            {
                footerTemplate.BeginText();
                footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);

                if (NumberSettings == PageNumbers.FooterPlacement)
                {
                }

                footerTemplate.EndText();
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace DataMngt.MyCode
{

    // used to define the fonts passed into the header and footer class
    public struct DefineFont
    {
        public string fontFamily { get; set; }
        public int fontSize { get; set; }
        public bool isBold { get; set; }
        public bool isItalic { get; set; }
        public bool isUnderlined { get; set; }
        public BaseColor foreColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To Use:

```
 Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL.Rotate(), 10, 10, 25, 25);
 System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, mStream);
 MyCode.HeaderFooter headers = new MyCode.HeaderFooter();
 writer.PageEvent = headers;
```

..
.. 
Build the string array for the headers
...

```
DefineFont passFont = new DefineFont();

    // always set this to the largest font used
    headers.fontPointSize = 8;

    // set up the highlight or bold font
    passFont.fontFamily = "Helvetica";
    passFont.fontSize = 8;
    passFont.isBold = true;
    passFont.isItalic = false;
    passFont.isUnderlined = false;
    passFont.foreColor = BaseColor.BLACK;

    headers.boldFont = passFont;

    // now setup the normal text font
    passFont.fontSize = 7;
    passFont.isBold = false;

    headers.normalFont = passFont;

    headers.leftMargin = 10;
    headers.bottomMargin = 25;
    headers.rightMargin = 10;
    headers.topMargin = 25;

    headers.PageNumberSettings = HeaderFooter.PageNumbers.FooterPlacement;

    headers.footerLine = "Page";
    headers.headerLines = parmLines.ToArray();

    pdfDoc.SetMargins(headers.leftMargin, headers.rightMargin, headers.topMargin + headers.headerheight, headers.bottomMargin + headers.footerHeight);
    pdfDoc.Open();

    // the new page is necessary due to a bug in in the current version of itextsharp
    pdfDoc.NewPage();
```

... now your headers and footer will be handled automatically

Comment: What do you think is the advantage of your solution in contrast to those in the existing answers?

Comment: Its a very generic routine that I use to generate headers and footers for a lot of reports that don't need an image header. Its easily adaptable with most uses only requiring a change of the properties.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to explain that because there is so much code hardly anyone will read it all and discover the advantages.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you out completely(the **Shortest** and **Most Elegant** way):

[Header Footer with PageEvent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0LzPszXzpI)

```
        PdfPTable tbheader = new PdfPTable(3);
        tbheader.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
        tbheader.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
        tbheader.AddCell(new Paragraph());
        tbheader.AddCell(new Paragraph());
        var _cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("This is my header", arial_italic));
        _cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        _cell2.Border = 0;
        tbheader.AddCell(_cell2);
        float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 20f, 60f };
        tbheader.SetWidths(widths);
        tbheader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin), writer.DirectContent);

        PdfPTable tbfooter = new PdfPTable(3);
        tbfooter.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
        tbfooter.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
        tbfooter.AddCell(new Paragraph());
        tbfooter.AddCell(new Paragraph());
        var _cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("This is my footer", arial_italic));
        _cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        _cell2.Border = 0;
        tbfooter.AddCell(_cell2);
        tbfooter.AddCell(new Paragraph());
        tbfooter.AddCell(new Paragraph());
        var _celly = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(writer.PageNumber.ToString()));//For page no.
        _celly.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        _celly.Border = 0;
        tbfooter.AddCell(_celly);
        float[] widths1 = new float[] { 20f, 20f, 60f };
        tbfooter.SetWidths(widths1);
        tbfooter.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, writer.PageSize.GetBottom(document.BottomMargin), writer.DirectContent);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25748759)

Comment: @stats0007:    Hope it is better now.

Answer (score -1):

```
pdfDoc.Open();
Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello World", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 22));
para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfDoc.Add(para);
pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\r\n"));
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @YatsBhavsar:  This will create header for one page, while we need it to be added to every page.