# iTextSharp - using PdfPageEventHelper to generate headers and footers for multiple PDF documents

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19004392/2430797 which illustrates an example of how to use page events with iTextSharp to generate headers and footers. I'd like to expand on this example and create a generic class in my application to generate the headers and footers of all my PDF documents. However, each document will have to have their own document title displayed in their header and their own document version displayed in their footer. Which means I need to use this class to create the headers with different header text and footer text for each PDF document.

I see the following declaration in the class of the respective example:

```
    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set { _header = value; }
    }
```

However, I'm not able to invoke it successfully using the "CreatePDF()" example as posted.

Can someone please help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you refer to, you have a class `ITextEvents` that is used like this:

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = new Common.ITextEvents();
```

This is strange, because this way, no header is set, nor can it be set.

You need to create an `ITextEvents` instance like this:

```
Common.ITextEvents event = new Common.ITextEvents();
event.Header = "My custom header";
pdfWriter.PageEvent = event;
```

While you are creating the document, you can change the header, if you don't want every page to have the same header.

**Important:**

The example you refer to has a number of pitfalls. For instance, it adds text like this:

```
cb.BeginText();
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
cb.SetTextMatrix(
    document.PageSize.GetRight(200), document.PageSize.GetTop(45));
cb.ShowText(header);
cb.EndText();
```

Are you sure you want to add text like this? This code snippet works, but it is for PDF specialists only.

I think you would prefer to reduce these six lines to this:

```
Phrase text = new Phrase(header);
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, text,
    document.PageSize.GetRight(200), document.PageSize.GetTop(45), 0);
```

It's much easier to understand the `ShowTextAligned()` method than to understand text graphics methods such as `BeginText()`, `SetFontAndSize()`, `SetTextMatrix()`, `ShowText()`, and `EndText()`.

I am worried for you because it seems that you are copying/pasting code from someone else without knowing what you are doing. I strongly recommend that you read some of the documentation available on [the official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/). If you just start using iText, you should probably also start using iText 7 for C# instead of iTextSharp 5.

Comment: The .NET code examples for iText 7 were finished last friday, they just haven't been published to the public yet, we'll get them up today.

Comment: @user2430797 What Samuel says is true for iText 7. If you use iText 5, you'll discover that all the examples for the book "iText in Action - Second Edition" are available as `cs` files at the bottom of the examples page of every chapter. You'll also discover that many of the answers in the FAQ use C# code. iText for Java is kept in sync with iText for C#. Every developer can easily switch between these two languages.