# header and footer using itextsharp using c#

Tags: c#, itext

I am using itextsharp for pdf generation using .net web applications. I have installed the following version of itextsharp using nuget package Install-Package iTextSharp -Version 5.5.10. I have seen the samples and developed 
code sample to generate the pdf and it is working. However i am not able to understand or get the header footer been  added to the pdf.  Here is the sample code i am using

```
public class Header : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    protected Phrase header;

    public void setHeader(Phrase header)
    {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header, 559, 806, 0);
    }
}   


Document pdfReport = null;
MemoryStream msReport = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfReport, msReport);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderText))
{
    Header objHeaderFooter = new Header();  
    //Here i need to assign the string HeaderText to Header. I dont know how to do it.                 
}
```

Please help to know how to assign HeaderText using itextSharp. Most of the developers examples are on java
but i am using .net c#.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996323/add-header-and-footer-for-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: solution sees to be complex. I am looking at a simpler approach to add the header and footer to the pdf file using c#

Comment: "solution is complex" is not an argument for rejecting it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Header and Footer for PDF using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996323/add-header-and-footer-for-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: Why are you using the coordinates `559, 806`? Are you sure those are right? You tell us in the comments of the answer that the header doesn't show up, but that would be very normal if `559, 806` is a coordinate outside the visible area of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assign `HeaderText` to `objHeaderFooter` in

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderText))
{
    Header objHeaderFooter = new Header();  
    //Here i need to assign the string HeaderText to Header. I dont know how to do it.                 
}
```

Assuming `HeaderText` to be a string you can do so using the `Header` method `setHeader`:

```
objHeaderFooter.setHeader(new Phrase(HeaderText));
```

Furthermore, you have to assign `objHeaderFooter` to your `PdfWriter` instance:

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = objHeaderFooter;
```

Thus:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderText))
{
    Header objHeaderFooter = new Header();  
    objHeaderFooter.setHeader(new Phrase(HeaderText));
    pdfWriter.PageEvent = objHeaderFooter;
}
```

Furthermore, whenever you override a method in c#, mark it accordingly as `override`. In particular in your page event listener, use

```
public override void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
```

This is easy to forget, especially when porting java examples because in java the corresponding marker `@Override` is optional.

---

Below is the sample code provided by the op.

```
Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.pdf");
            Response.Charset = "";            
            Response.BinaryWrite(getbinary());
            Response.End();  

  public byte[] getbinary()
        {
            Document pdfReport = null;
            pdfReport = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 40, 25);
            MemoryStream msReport = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfReport, msReport);

            pdfReport.Open();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("Header Text"))
            {
                Header objHeaderFooter = new Header();
                objHeaderFooter.SetHeader(new Phrase("Header Text"));
                pdfWriter.PageEvent = objHeaderFooter;
            }

            PdfPTable ptData1 = new PdfPTable(1);
            ptData1.SpacingBefore = 8;
            ptData1.DefaultCell.Padding = 1;
            ptData1.WidthPercentage = 100;
            ptData1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            ptData1.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

            PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
            cell1.BorderWidth = 0.001F;
            cell1.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(250, 250, 250);
            cell1.BorderColor = new BaseColor(100, 100, 100);
            cell1.Phrase = new Phrase("Sample text");
            ptData1.AddCell(cell1);


            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.BorderWidth = 0.001F;
            cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(200, 200, 200);
            cell.BorderColor = new BaseColor(100, 100, 100);

            cell.Phrase = new Phrase("test value");
            ptData1.AddCell(cell);
            pdfReport.Add(ptData1);

            pdfReport.Close();
            return  msReport.ToArray();

        }

public class Header : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        protected Phrase header;

        public void SetHeader(Phrase header)
        {
            this.header = header;
        }

        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header, 559, 806, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried doing it .but still i don't see the header in the pdf. Is there anything missed. or is it browser specific

Comment: It is not browser specific. Thus, something is missing. Unfortunately your code is no [sscce](http://sscce.org), so I cannot use it to check.

Comment: a short sample using c# would help me,

Comment: I'm currently only on a smart phone. I'll look into that later.

Comment: @jaiganesh I think you misunderstood mkl (and I hope you didn't do that intentionally). Mkl asked you to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), which means that *you* need to provide an example, so that *we* can take a look at what you are doing wrong. There are literally hundreds of examples on the [official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/page-events-itext-5). Why don't you try one of those examples? I am very tempted to close your question as it has been answered many times before, and the answer isn't complex at all!

Comment: Below is the code sample
Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.pdf");
            Response.Charset = "";            
            Response.BinaryWrite(getbinary());
            Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

May be this could be used as a workaround. Added header as another cell value
Below is the code

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderText))
            {
                PdfPTable Header = new PdfPTable(1);
                Header.SpacingBefore = 8;
                Header.DefaultCell.Padding = 1;
                Header.WidthPercentage = 100;
                Header.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                Header.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

                PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
                cell1.BorderWidth = 0.001F;
                cell1.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(250, 250, 250);
                cell1.BorderColor = new BaseColor(100, 100, 100);
                cell1.Phrase = new Phrase(HeaderText, fontBold);
                Header.AddCell(cell1);
                pdfReport.Add(ptDataHeader);
            }
```

Comment: Does your answer relate in any way with your question?   You asked for adding headers and footers to a file and now you consider a table once solves that problem?

Comment: I have unmarked the answer and marked the other one which i have updated earlier. How ever the mistake was in the below line. It should have been as  public override void OnnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)  which was working.

Comment: that indeed is extremely important. As you accepted my answer, I added a remark on that to it. I suppose I hadn't really looked at the `Header` code as the question focussed on *how to assign HeaderText using itextSharp*.