# How to add footer to pdf page when page is added using iTextSharp Stamper.InsertPage method

Tags: c#, itext, pdfstamper

I am adding `Pdftable` to existing pdf, Existing pdf already has `footer` but in some cases if table rows are more, I am inserting new page using

```
stamper.InsertPage(pagecount, pagesize);
```

But I am not sure how I can add `footer` to this newly added page. What I have tried up to now is

```
 stamper.Writer.PageEvent = new PdfFooterClass()
  {
      //Below are the properties of pdfFooterClass whose values used for footer.
      Title = "My Sample Page"
      UserId = "007" 
  };
```

But this doesn't work, Please suggest what will be the right method to add `footer` while inserting page using `stamper`. 
I am adding my new page with different method than used in this [Add Header and Footer for PDF using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996323/add-header-and-footer-for-pdf-using-itextsharp) so this does't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Header and Footer for PDF using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996323/add-header-and-footer-for-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: @FeiShengWu That one is using document instance pdfwriter getInstance, In my case I am already editing page and adding page using stamper.InsertPage method.

Comment: @FeiShengWu My problem is getting event for newly added page, The above one doesnt address it when page added using stamper.

Comment: Page events only are triggered when itext creates pages automatically when you add content to a `Document`. When you yourself add pages manually, there is no need for page events, simply draw the footer onto each page you add manually.